# Namespace Implementation

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I am trying to implement the functionality of namespaces. The main class Project contains a vector `std::vector std::shared_ptr<Class>classes_{};` Each class, respectively, contains similar vectors with Variable and Function. Also, the Class class can have a base class - `Class* parent_`. The task is such, for example, when adding a new variable (in Class `std::vector std::shared_ptr<Variable> vars_{};`) or renaming an existing one, it was checked (taking into account visibility) that a variable with such a name does not exist in this class and all his ancestors. The names of the created functions and classes were also checked, etc.

Below is my implementation that I don't like.

1. `Variable::parent_` can be both a class and a function. It is logical to assume that Class, if it does not have a parent class, `parent_` was not `nullptr`, but `Project*`. In principle, this can be solved by having all classes store `Nameable* parent_` rather than a concrete class. But then every time you access `parent_` you would have to downcast the pointer.
2. Traversing all Nameable objects creates a set of temporary vectors (in `Nameable::nameables()` and in `Nameable::get_nameables()`).

Please advise how to solve these problems. Or perhaps where you can peep a more beautiful implementation

```
#include "string"
#include "string_view"
#include "vector"
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>


class Nameable
{
    std::string     name_{};
    //VISIBILITY visibility_{ VISIBILITY::PUBLIC };
protected:
    virtual Nameable* parent() const = 0;
    virtual std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Nameable>> nameables() const = 0;
    void get_nameables(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Nameable>>& n)
    {
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Nameable>> names = nameables();
        if (parent()) 
            parent()->get_nameables(names);
        n.insert(n.end(), names.begin(), names.end());
    }
public:
    Nameable(std::string_view name) : name_(name)
    {
        //if (!check_name(name)) throw InvalidNameException(name);
    }
    virtual ~Nameable() {};

    std::shared_ptr<Nameable> check_name(std::string_view name) const
    { 
        return std::shared_ptr<Nameable>();
    }
    const std::string& get_name() const& { return name_; }
    void               set_name(std::string_view name) { name_ = name; }
};

class Variable;
class Function;

class Class final : public Nameable
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Variable>> vars_{};
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Function>> funs_{};

    Class* parent_{};

    Nameable* parent() const override 
    {
        return parent_; 
    }

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Nameable>> nameables() const override
    {
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Nameable>> n{};
        n.insert(n.end(), vars_.begin(), vars_.end());
        n.insert(n.end(), funs_.begin(), funs_.end());
        return n;
    }

public:
    Class(std::string_view name, Class* parent = nullptr)
        : Nameable(name), parent_(parent) 
    {}

    std::shared_ptr<Variable> create_var(std::string_view name)
    {
        vars_.push_back(std::make_shared<Variable>(name, this));
        return vars_.back();
    }

    std::shared_ptr<Function> create_fun(std::string_view name)
    {
        funs_.push_back(std::make_shared<Function>(name, this));
        return funs_.back();
    }
};


class Variable final : public Nameable
{
    Class* parent_{};
    Nameable* parent() const override 
    {
        return parent_; 
    }

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Nameable>> nameables() const override
    {
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Nameable>> n{};
        return n; // return empty vector
    }

public:
    Variable(std::string_view name, Class* parent) 
        : Nameable(name), parent_(parent) {}
};


class Function final : public Nameable
{
    Class* parent_{};
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Variable>> local_vars_{};

    Nameable* parent() const override 
    { 
        return parent_; 
    }

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Nameable>> nameables() const override
    {
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Nameable>> n{};
        n.insert(n.end(), local_vars_.begin(), local_vars_.end());
        return n;
    }

public:
    Function(std::string_view name, Class* parent)
        : Nameable(name), parent_(parent) {}
};


class Project final : public Nameable
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Class>> classes_{};

    Nameable* parent() const override { return nullptr; }

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Nameable>> nameables() const override
    {
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Nameable>> n{};
        n.insert(n.end(), classes_.begin(), classes_.end());
        return n;
    }

public:
    Project(std::string_view name) : Nameable(name){}
};
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's really a CodeReview question as phrased.  It might be worthwhile to edit it to ask specifically about whether the use of dynamic polymorphism here is warranted.

Comment: Ideally, the concept of namespaces is basically a method of grouping symbols, in a symbol table.  What are the definitions and rules for namespaces in your language?

Comment: You could use a tree to represent the namespace groups, and then a list of symbols in that namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your intent clearly, yet maybe use composition instead? It's just easier to maintain. It'd be easier for me if you have provided any use case, but nonetheless I have something like below for you.

```
    // You may want use it in a bitfield mask manner.
    enum class NameType : int8_t {
        Function = 1,
        Variable = 2,
        Object = 4,
        None = 8
    };

    // Just simple storage, defaulted if constructed with a default constructor.
    struct Nameable {
        // union := variable | static_function
        using Parent = std::variant<std::optional<std::any>, std::function<std::any(std::any)>>;

        explicit Nameable(std::string_view sv, NameType t, const Parent& p = std::nullopt): name(sv), type(t), parent(p)
        {
        }

        std::string name{};
        NameType type = NameType::None;
        Parent parent = std::nullopt;
    };

    // Flat aggregator of names (no hierarchy mapping), one-for-all (e.g. per class, per namespace).
    struct Collector {
        using Nameables = std::vector<std::optional<Nameable>>;

        explicit Collector(std::string_view sv, NameType t, const std::optional<std::any>& p = std::nullopt)
        {
            attach(sv, t, p);
        }

        void attach(std::string_view sv, NameType t, const std::optional<std::any>& p = std::nullopt)
        {
            auto n = Nameable(sv, t, p);
            names.emplace_back(std::move(n));
        }

        // combine collectors, such that (f+g)(n) := f(n) + g(n), e.g. for namespace, module, translation unit.
        [[maybe_unused]] void attach(const Collector& c)
        {
            for (const auto& name: c.names) {
                attach(name->name, name->type, name->parent);
            }
        }

        bool isUniqueName(std::string_view key) const
        {
            return std::ranges::all_of(names, [key](const auto& name) {
                if (name.has_value() && name.value().name == key) return false;
                return true;
            });
        }

        bool isUniqueObjectName(std::string_view key) const
        {
            return std::ranges::all_of(names, [key](const auto& name) {
                if (name.has_value() && name.value().type == NameType::Object && name.value().name == key) return false;
                return true;
            });
        }

        std::size_t index(std::string_view key) const
        {
            for (std::size_t i = 0; i != names.size(); ++i) {
                const auto& name = names[i];
                if (name.has_value() && name.value().name == key) return i;
            }

            return std::string::npos;
        }

        void rename(std::string_view from, std::string_view to)
        {
            names.at(index(from)).value().name = std::string(to);
        }

        const Nameable& get(std::string_view key) const
        {
            if (!names.at(index(key)).has_value()) throw std::bad_optional_access();
            return names.at(index(key)).value();
        }

        std::any variable(std::string_view name) const
        {
            const auto& nameable = get(name);

            if (const auto& var = nameable.parent; std::holds_alternative<std::optional<std::any>>(var)) {
                if (const auto& opt = std::get<0>(var); opt.has_value()) return opt.value();
                throw std::bad_optional_access();
            }

            throw std::bad_variant_access();
        }

        Nameables names{};
    };
```

The idea is to collect names hierarchically but through "formation". Alternatively, just use trees, or dictionaries (as it has been already stated).

```
namespace outer {
    Collector cOuter;
    constexpr int GLOBAL = 1;

    namespace inner {
        Collector cInner;
        void f() {}

        namespace internal {
            Collector cInternal;
            Data d{};
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not certain if you're really interested in storing objects, though.
With std::any it may require some gymnastic, but you can handle it.
I would suggest std::optional, but this need trivially copyable structure, so be careful with adding new fields. Collecting member functions require some additional std::function signature. If you need more information, e.g. about types, then store them as type traits, or concepts, or anyhow. Eventually, introduce std::variant<Variable, Function, Class/Object>. Let give them do their job (Variable/+types, Function/+params, Class/+hierarchy) and compose them at the end.

```
    struct SomeClass {
        static auto Something(int y = 3) noexcept
        {
            return 1 + y;
        }

        int var1 = 0;
        float var2 = 5.5;
    };
    SomeClass s{};

    auto c = Collector("SomeClass", NameType::Object, s);
    c.attach("var1", NameType::Variable, s.var1);
    c.attach("var2", NameType::Variable, s.var2);
    c.attach("Something", NameType::Function, SomeClass::Something);

    std::cout << c.names[0].value().name << '\n'; // "SomeClass", etc.

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << c.isUniqueName("var1") << '\n'; // false
    c.rename("var1", "var_1");
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << c.isUniqueName("var1") << '\n'; // true
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << c.isUniqueObjectName("SomeClass") << '\n'; // false

    auto var2 = c.variable("var2");
    auto vf = std::any_cast<float>(var2);
    std::cout << std::to_string(vf) << '\n'; // 5.500000
```